# Windows 7 Ethernet over USB (RDNIS) works but is very slow to acquire IP Address

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, usb, ethernet

I have a Windows 7 64-bit Professional machine connected to the internet through a Netgear N300 Router. I also have a small Linux based camera that does Ethernet over USB (RDNIS). When I plug in the Linux device to the Windows 7 machine, it takes about 50-60 seconds to obtain an IP Address on the 10.XXX.00.X network from Windows. In Windows XP with the same configuration, the IP Address is obtained almost immediately!

After the minute of waiting, everything is fine. I can ping and otherwise use the connected Linux device anyway I want.

Why does it take so long to obtain an IP Address for the device under Windows 7 and how can I troubleshoot or fix this?  Is there some sort of priority setting needed?

Thanks!

NOTE:
Using Microsoft Network Monitor when I plug in my device I immediately receive the following:

```
271 9:26:07 AM 1/17/2013    218.8801397     0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 DHCP    DHCP:Request, MsgType = REQUEST, TransactionID = 0xBDBD6E0C {DHCP:53, UDP:7, IPv4:6}
272 9:26:07 AM 1/17/2013    218.8812374     10.130.0.2  PC-MSP-183B     DHCP    DHCP:Reply, MsgType = ACK, TransactionID = 0xBDBD6E0C   {DHCP:53, UDP:7, IPv4:6}
273 9:26:07 AM 1/17/2013    218.9334041     0.0.0.0 PC-MSP-183B     ARP ARP:Request, 0.0.0.0 asks for 10.130.0.1
```

Comment: Grab a copy of Wireshark or Microsoft Network Monitor and see how long it takes for a DHCP discovery to come out of your slow client. I suspect that the Windows 7 is takings its time to install drivers.

Comment: Shouldn't the driver already be installed? I use this device quite a bit ( several months now ) but it still consistently takes about a minute to get an IP Address. I used NetWork Monitor and can see the DHCP Request immediately when plugging the Linux device into Windows.

Comment: My Windows 7 box reinstalls the keyboard and mouse drivers every time they switch USB slots, same thing with my wireless USB device.

Comment: Is it Ethernet over USB, or is it RNDIS? If it's RNDIS, I get this problem too -- I thought it was Link-Layer Topology Discovery, but I disabled it and it's still slow. I asked a question about this on SU before but nobody had an answer. [See here](http://superuser.com/questions/446495/rndis-connection-lag-on-windows-not-linux).

Comment: Yes it's RNDIS - that is strange that you see the same issue. Is it different for you on Windows XP as well?